# How to hide the error label in Xamarin forms, when the Entry field is not visible?

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism

I am trying to create a Login page that has validation errors. Right now the validation errors are also appearing if the Entry field is not visible. How would I hide the error labels, when the entry field is not visible? As shown below: The PIN entry field is invisible on the login page but the error message: **Pin is required**, highlights. Please could anyone suggest a workaround?

[image]

Comment: bind the IsVisible property of the error field to the same model property as the Entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with **Jason** . You can use the data-binding to binding the `IsVisible` of label to the property in your viewmodel.

```
<Label Text="Pin is required!"  TextColor="Red"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding isVisible}"/>

<Button Text="sign in" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"  WidthRequest="200" />
```

#### in your ViewModel

```
public class YourViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ICammand ClickCommand {get; set;}


    private bool isvisible;

    public bool isVisible
    {
     get
     {
        return isvisible;
     }

     set
     {
      if (isvisible!= value)
      {
        isvisible= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
      }
    }


    public YourViewModel()
    {
        //... 
        isVisible = true; //show the label in default
         
        ClickCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
           if(xxx)
           {
              isVisible =false;
           }
           
           else
           { 
              isVisible =true;
           }
        }) ;

    }

}
```