# How to bind app-settings to an edited EntryCell from TableView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm working with Xamarin and C# since two weeks now, but I'm really struggling with making an enterprise like MVVM-Pattern work.
I'm stuck since two days so I thought I ask the experts, the community.

My problem was the fact that an EntryCell doesn't have the attribut "IsPassword", so I created a CostumCell which is a ViewCell with an Grid, Labeland Entryinside. This Entryis able to have the "IsPassword" attribut, which I found here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17530/ispassword-is-there-for-entry-but-not-for-entrycell

So now to the actual problem.
The EditedEntryCell is not able to show binded text, in fact anything. The normal EntryCell is able to show it all:
SettingsPage.xaml

```xml
<TableSection>
    <EntryCell
        Label="normal entry"
        Text="{Binding Username}"/>
    <EntryCell
        Label="normal entry"
        Text="{Binding Password}"/>
    <local:EditedEntryCell
        LabelText="edited entry"
        EntryText="{Binding Password}"
        EntryIsPassword="True"/>
</TableSection>
```

When I'm building this is appearing in the output:

[0:] Binding: 'LabelText' property not found on 'ProblemDemonstration.ViewModel.SettingsPageViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

[0:] Binding: 'EntryText' property not found on 'ProblemDemonstration.ViewModel.SettingsPageViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text'

[0:] Binding: 'EntryIsPassword' property not found on 'ProblemDemonstration.ViewModel.SettingsPageViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.IsPassword'

I don't understand why the Binding is trying to find the attributes on the ViewModel and not on the EditedEntryCell Class, because they are useable through

`xaml xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProblemDemonstration.Extensions"`

The Code-Behind looks like this:
SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UsernameProperty =
               BindableProperty.Create(
                   propertyName: "Username",
                   returnType: typeof(string),
                   declaringType: typeof(SettingsPageViewModel));

        public static readonly BindableProperty PasswordProperty =
               BindableProperty.Create(
                   propertyName: "Password",
                   returnType: typeof(string),
                   declaringType: typeof(SettingsPageViewModel));
        public string Username
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UsernameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UsernameProperty, value); }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
        }
        public SettingsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new SettingsPageViewModel(((App)Application.Current).Settings);
        }
    }
```

This shows the CustomCell definition:

EditedEntryCell.xaml

```xml
<ViewCell ...>
    <Grid>
        ....
        <Label
            Text="{Binding LabelText}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            IsVisible="{Binding BothIsVisible}"/>
        <Entry
            Text="{Binding EntryText}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            IsPassword="{Binding EntryIsPassword}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EntryIsEnabled}"
            IsVisible="{Binding BothIsVisible}"/>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

EditedEntryCell.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class EditedEntryCell : ViewCell
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "LabelText",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(EditedEntryCell),
                defaultValue: "default");

        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "EntryText",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(EditedEntryCell),
                defaultValue: "default");

        .....

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
        } 
        public string EntryText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(EntryTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryTextProperty, value); }
        }

        ....
    }
```

Code in the ViewModel:
SettingsPageViewModel.xaml.cs

```cs
public class SettingsPageViewModel
    {
        private Settings _settings;

        public string Username
        {
            get { return _settings.Username; }
            set { _settings.Username = value; }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get { return _settings.Password; }
            set { _settings.Password = value; }
        }

        public SettingsPageViewModel(Settings settings)
        {
            this._settings = settings;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it understandle what I'm asking?

Comment: Can you share the code in your ViewModel?

Comment: I added the code of the ViewModel

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609258/how-to-hide-the-error-label-in-xamarin-forms-when-the-entry-field-is-not-visibl.

Comment: I don't get it. I don't think this helps me. My Problem is that BindingContext works for normal EntryCells but not for the CustomEntryCell.

Comment: Could you share the sample so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjtfzjy3sk91pfb/ProblemDemonstration%20.zip?dl=0

Comment: Don't forget to remove your personal info ,such as password and account ID.

Comment: Thanks for the info but it should be nothing in there.

Comment: Where you able to open it?

Comment: I have downloaded it and will provide you a solution later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Appreciate it very much! :D
The link is now offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:** It seems you forgot to set the `BindingContext` of `CustomEntryCell` .So the binding will never work.

**Solution:** Add the following code

```
public EditedEntryCell()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: This solved it too. Thank you very much. Like this <https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/387065#Comment_387065>